# How to localize numbers only?

Tags: django

I have a Django app with all texts and controls in English, but I need to show numbers in the correct local format; i.e. using appropriate symbols for decimal points and thousands separation. Everything else, including dates, I would like to keep in English format.

With **USE_L10N=True** and **USE_I18N=True**, all numbers and dates get formatted according to the language set in HTTP headers.

With **USE_L10N=True** and **USE_I18N=False**, only numbers get formatted, but the language set in HTTP headers is ignored; i.e. the numbers are formatted according to settings.LANGUAGE_CODE. This seems to be by design: [django/utils/translation/trans_null.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/translation/trans_null.py)

I must be missing something. What is the best practice for localising numbers only? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For lack of a better solution, I've created the following filter:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django import template
from django.utils import numberformat
from django.utils.formats import get_format

register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
    def localnumber(value, lang=None):
        lang = lang or settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
        return numberformat.format(
            value,
            get_format("DECIMAL_SEPARATOR", lang, use_l10n=True),
            None,
            get_format("NUMBER_GROUPING", lang, use_l10n=True),
            get_format("THOUSAND_SEPARATOR", lang, use_l10n=True),
            force_grouping=True,
            use_l10n=True,
        )
```

In my template I use the filter as follows:

```
{% with lang=request.META.HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE %}

<span>{{ my_var_with_raw_number|localnumber:lang }}</span>

{% endwith %}
```

Not ideal, but it may help to someone as a temporary solution.